# What happens after a packet is captured?

Tags: linux, rss, windows-installer, packet, dma

I've been reading about what happens after packets are captured by NICs, and the more I read, the more I'm confused.

Firstly, I've read that traditionally, after a packet is captured by the NIC, it gets copied to a block of memory in the kernel space, then to the user space for whatever application that then works on the packet data. Then I read about DMA, where the NIC directly copies the packet into memory, bypassing the CPU. So is the NIC -> kernel memory -> User space memory flow still valid? Also, do most NIC (e.g. Myricom) use DMA to improve packet capture rates?

Secondly, does RSS (Receive Side Scaling) work similarly in both Windows and Linux systems? I can only find detailed explanations on how RSS works in MSDN articles, where they talk about how RSS (and MSI-X) works on Windows Server 2008. But the same concept of RSS and MSI-X should still apply for linux systems, right?

Thank you.

Regards,
Rayne

Comment: Google for zero copy networking... very few high speed devices can tolerate double-copy to kernel then user these days. IANANG (I Am Not A Network Guru) but I believe DMA is used aggressively

Comment: So nowadays, once a NIC captures a packet, it'll be directly copied into (user) memory?

Comment: @Rayne yes; the NIC will use DMA to transfer data directly into physical memory mapped into your process' (userland) address space.

Comment: Why do you ask? What do you like to achieve?

Comment: +1 for mentioning zero-copy. Its widely used now a days.

Comment: @Vlad: When the packet arrives, the user application may not have asked for the data yet, so it's impossible to copy it into a user-space buffer. It's stored in the kernel until requested.

Comment: @vladr As u have have mentioned that NIC directly copies the packet in the user space process's memory with the help of DMA & uses only one copy...But I think DMA is used only for transferring the data in the kernel memory without CPU intervention so coping the data doesn't happen with the help of CPU & CPU may work at the time of DMA transfer.

Answer (score 19):

How this process plays out is mostly up to the driver author and the hardware, but for the drivers I've looked at or written and the hardware I've worked with, this is usually the way it works:

1. At driver initialization, it will allocate some number of buffers and give these to the NIC.
2. When a packet is received by the NIC, it pulls the next address off its list of buffers, DMAs the data directly into it, and notifies the driver via an interrupt.
3. The driver gets the interrupt, and can either turn the buffer over to the kernel or it will allocate a new kernel buffer and copy the data. "Zero copy networking" is the former and obviously requires support from the operating system. (more below on this)
4. The driver needs to either allocate a new buffer (in the zero-copy case) or it will re-use the buffer. In either case, the buffer is given back to the NIC for future packets.

Zero-copy networking within the kernel isn't so bad. Zero-copy all the way down to userland is *much* harder. Userland gets data, but network packets are made up of both header and data. At the least, true zero-copy all the way to userland requires support from your NIC so that it can DMA packets into separate header/data buffers. The headers are recycled once the kernel routes the packet to its destination and verifies the checksum (for TCP, either in hardware if the NIC supports it or in software if not; note that if the kernel has to compute the checksum itself, it'd may as well copy the data, too: looking at the data incurs cache misses and copying it elsewhere can be for free with tuned code).

Even assuming all the stars align, the data isn't actually in your user buffer when it is received by the system. Until an application asks for the data, the kernel doesn't know where it will end up. Consider the case of a multi-process daemon like Apache. There are many child processes, all listening on the same socket. You can also establish a connection, `fork()`, and both processes are able to `recv()` incoming data.

TCP packets on the Internet are usually 1460 bytes of payload (MTU of 1500 = 20 byte IP header + 20 byte TCP header + 1460 bytes data). 1460 is not a power of 2 and won't match a page size on any system you'll find. This presents problems for reassembly of the data stream. Remember that TCP is stream-oriented. There is no distinction between sender writes, and two 1000 byte writes waiting at the received will be consumed entirely in a 2000 byte read.

Taking this further, consider the user buffers. These are allocated by the application. In order to be used for zero-copy all the way down, the buffer needs to be page-aligned and not share that memory page with anything else. At `recv()` time, the kernel could theoretically remap the old page with the one containing the data and "flip" it into place, but this is complicated by the reassembly issue above since successive packets will be on separate pages. The kernel could limit the data it hands back to each packet's payload, but this will mean a lot of additional system calls, page remapping and likely lower throughput overall.

I'm really only scratching the surface on this topic. I worked at a couple of companies in the early 2000s trying to extend the zero-copy concepts down into userland. We even implemented a TCP stack in userland and circumvented the kernel entirely for applications using the stack, but that brought its own set of problems and was never production quality. It's a very hard problem to solve.

Answer (score -1):

take a look at this paper, http://www.ece.virginia.edu/cheetah/documents/papers/TCPlinux.pdf it might help clearing out some of the memory management questions